# ¿Dónde y en qué contexto se usa "de oquis"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, coloquialismos, méxico, locuciones

Leyendo *Salvar el fuego* del mexicano Guillermo Arriaga me encuentro con:

> (...) Las manos le temblaban. Darle mate al Patotas había sido diferente que matar a su padre. A su padre lo había quemado vivo para incinerar la rabia. Ahora había asesinado a un chamaco baboso nomás **de oquis**.

Para dar contexto, el protagonista acaba de asesinar a un joven por una serie de circunstancias, pero en definitiva de forma un tanto gratuita. Hay distintas palabras que me sorprenden (y centenares a lo largo del libro), pero en este caso concreto fue la expresión *de oquis*, que el DAMER define como:

> a. ǁ [**de oquis**](https://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=amoEbMlBZx0A2i3QNbj).
> i.    loc. adv/adj. Mx. De balde, en vano. (de hoquis; deoquis; dioquis).
> ii.   loc. adv. Mx. Gratuitamente. (de hoquis; deoquis; dioquis).

Es decir, que quiere decir *gratuitamente*. El DLE lo recoge así:

> [**oque**](https://dle.rae.es/oque)
> Cf. hoque.
> **de oque**
> 1. loc. adv. [de balde](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4sRIVm1#MckyuJN).

Donde *de balde* viene *Del ár. hisp. báṭil, y este del ár. clás. bāṭil 'vano', 'inútil', 'sin valor'.* y significa *Gratuitamente, sin coste alguno*, *en vano* o *Sin motivo, sin causa.*

Tirando de lo de *Cf. hoque* (*Cf* significa *confer*, es decir, que toca mirar la palabra *hoque*) vamos a:

> [**hoque**](https://dle.rae.es/hoque)
> *Del ár. hisp. ḥáqq, y este del ár. clás. ḥaqq 'retribución'.*
> 1. m. Regalo que se hace a quienes intervienen en una venta.

No me sonaba para nada la expresión y veo que se usa también *dioquis*, *de oque* o *de oquis*.

Nunca la oí mencionar en España en ninguna de sus variantes, pese a que su origen árabe hace pensar que debería provenir de por aquí. ¿Qué uso tiene esta expresión? Yo la encontré en un habla muy coloquial y de jerga mexicana. ¿Es únicamente algo coloquial?

Answer (score 2):

Solo por aportar más documentación a esta entrada, el escritor mexicano Arturo Ortega Morán cita el *Vocabulario de Refranes y Frases Proverbiales* de Correas (1627) en este [interesante artículo](https://capsuladelengua.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/de-hoquis/) publicado originalmente en periódico *El Horizonte*.

> **De hoke**: Dízese kuando alguno toma o se le da algo de más de lo
> prinzipal, komo por vía de soborno o aprovechamiento; kasi lo mesmo
> ke: «De sotake».
> «Kiere llevárselo de hoke»: de balde.
>  «Kiere esto u
> estotro de hoke» y también
>  Komer de hoke. Por: «Komer de balde» entre
> otros, i de sakaliñas

Yo hubiera apostado que tendría alguna relación con el **ok** norteamericano, pero parece que no es así.

No es relevante pero yo personalmente no he oído ni leído nunca esa expresión aquí en España. Quizás por su desuso acabaron eliminándola del DRAE, a pesar de que salía en anteriores ediciones - 1927, 1957, 1984,  y 1989, según indica Ortega Morán -.

Comment: A mí me pasó lo mismo al ver el _ok_, sobre todo en el contexto de habla coloquial mexicana de narcos y demás (muy influenciados por el hablar inglés). ¿Será que de alguna forma ha "resurgido" el término al pensar que la expresión es gringa? En el libro hay muchíiiiisimas expresiones que sí lo son.

Comment: Even if it does come from OK (which I too doubt) that gets us further into the mire as there must be almost as many proposed etymologies for Ok as for any other word in English as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proposed_etymologies_of_OK attests.